# How do 2nd ed Diaspora Consequences work?

Tags: diaspora, fate-2.0, consequences

I'm familiar with Consequences in modern Fate-- Characters gain an Aspect temporarily that represents the 'injury' sustained and that aspect gives enemies something to invoke for bonuses against the character.

However, I'm *not* familiar with any such Consequence system in FATE 2.0, yet [I hear](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62890/how-can-i-play-a-survival-based-fate-2-0-game-where-access-to-items-plays-a-majo/63164?noredirect=1#comment249715_63164) that one exists in a pre-3rd edition run of [Diaspora](http://www.evilhat.com/home/diaspora-3/) (linked is the 3rd edition version).  How did Consequences work in this material?  How did they interact with the hit point system on page 36 of the 2.0 rulebook?  Did they still add aspects like in 3rd edition and later?  If so, how did they avoid consequences being strictly positive for players (or was that intended)?

Comment: Hmm, we probably have a misalignment on what we call 2.0 and 3.0 here. There's only one Diaspora, and it is rooted on Fate 2.0. The concepts it introduced however, (along with DFRPG and others) were **later** dubbed 3.0. Consequences are one of them. What I (and the authors of Diaspora) consider 2.0 is first seen on Spirit of the Century. The 2.0 and 3.0 labels were both postfix. There's some ambiguity in how they apply. Actually, Fate Core was introduced to consolidate all those interpretations and clarify ambiguities.

Comment: Maybe that is partially an answer to [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100158/554)

Comment: Evil Hat originally started work on SotC with a big banner talking about how it was going to be a preview of the upcoming third edition rules.  The 2nd edition was released for free under the name FATE 2.0 on the official website at that time.  SotC is widely regarded as the turning point of FATE 3.0 and is nowhere regarded as 2nd edition FATE as far as I'm aware. I already linked the official site, but here's some other sources: http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/79933/Diaspora,  page 4 of the Diaspora SRD, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate_(role-playing_game_system)#Fate_3rd_Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way consequences work in *Diaspora* hasn't changed across editions — the “3rd edition” there has the original meaning of the word “edition”, which is just a reprinting edition that contains corrections without any major changes. (In D&D vernacular, these are errata updates, not editions.) The published editions of *Diaspora* are all the same game, in other words. How consequences work in *Diaspora* editions hasn't changed, and works the same as in *Spirit of the Century* — aspects created in reaction to excess stress — but with the usual numerical tweaks to exactly how much of a stress hit they can mitigate, as is common among “Fate 3” games.

There are old PDFs of pre-publication *Diaspora* though, when it was going to be called *Spirit of the Far Future* and it was much more obvious (if that's possible) that it's a love letter to *Traveller*. The earliest I have is the December 2, 2007 revision (`SotFF-02122007.pdf`) that I once pulled off a website of the designers' (which is no longer maintained, and appears to be [incompletely archived by the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://phreeow.net/sotff//*)). This revision is still obviously a modification of *Spirit of the Century* (i.e., “Fate 3”) in not just name but also in design, and consequences in even these early drafts of *Spirit of the Far Future* work the same as in *Spirit of the Century*, again with the common tweaking.

To my knowledge there's no edition or draft of *Diaspora* that was based on the FATE 2.0 ruleset. When it was *SotFF* and I first started tracking its development, it was very much a *SoC* rewrite project. I'm afraid that *Diaspora*'s development contains no pearls of wisdom about how consequences might be integrated into FATE 2.0.

Comment: Well, I was gonna just go ahead and delete the question cause it turned out it was based on a misunderstanding, but this is quite an excellent answer, and it's cool to learn about pre-print Diaspora! I think I'll leave it up, then.